# class labels in Pandas scattermatrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, scatter-plot

This question has been asked before, [Multiple data in scatter matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21131707/1586229), but didn't receive an answer.

I'd like to make a scatter matrix, something like [in the pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot-matrix), but with differently colored markers for different classes. For example, I'd like some points to appear in green and others in blue depending on the value of one of the columns (or a separate list).

Here's an example using the Iris dataset. The color of the points represents the species of Iris -- Setosa, Versicolor, or Virginica.

[image: iris scattermatrix with class labels]

Does pandas (or matplotlib) have a way to make a chart like that?

Comment: look into the seaborn project: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html (builds off of pandas and matplotlib)

Comment: @PaulH, thanks for the link, that looks really useful. It looks like the functionality I'm looking for is still in the works: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/63 .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Update: This functionality is now in the latest version of Seaborn. [Here's an example](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html).

The following was my stopgap measure:

```
def factor_scatter_matrix(df, factor, palette=None):
    '''Create a scatter matrix of the variables in df, with differently colored
    points depending on the value of df[factor].
    inputs:
        df: pandas.DataFrame containing the columns to be plotted, as well 
            as factor.
        factor: string or pandas.Series. The column indicating which group 
            each row belongs to.
        palette: A list of hex codes, at least as long as the number of groups.
            If omitted, a predefined palette will be used, but it only includes
            9 groups.
    '''
    import matplotlib.colors
    import numpy as np
    from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
    from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

    if isinstance(factor, basestring):
        factor_name = factor #save off the name
        factor = df[factor] #extract column
        df = df.drop(factor_name,axis=1) # remove from df, so it 
        # doesn't get a row and col in the plot.

    classes = list(set(factor))

    if palette is None:
        palette = ['#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4eae4b', 
                   '#994fa1', '#ff8101', '#fdfc33', 
                   '#a8572c', '#f482be', '#999999']

    color_map = dict(zip(classes,palette))

    if len(classes) > len(palette):
        raise ValueError('''Too many groups for the number of colors provided.
We only have {} colors in the palette, but you have {}
groups.'''.format(len(palette), len(classes)))

    colors = factor.apply(lambda group: color_map[group])
    axarr = scatter_matrix(df,figsize=(10,10),marker='o',c=colors,diagonal=None)


    for rc in xrange(len(df.columns)):
        for group in classes:
            y = df[factor == group].icol(rc).values
            gkde = gaussian_kde(y)
            ind = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 1000)
            axarr[rc][rc].plot(ind, gkde.evaluate(ind),c=color_map[group])

    return axarr, color_map
```

As an example, we'll use the same dataset as in the question, available [here](https://raw.github.com/pydata/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/iris.csv)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> iris = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
>>> axarr, color_map = factor_scatter_matrix(iris,'Name')
>>> color_map
{'Iris-setosa': '#377eb8',
 'Iris-versicolor': '#4eae4b',
 'Iris-virginica': '#e41a1c'}
```

[image: iris_scatter_matrix]

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: In case anyone ends up here through search, as of seaborn 0.4 this should be pretty easy. [Here's](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html) a basic example.

Answer (score 19):

You can also call the scattermatrix from pandas as follow :

```
pd.scatter_matrix(df,color=colors)
```

with `colors` being an list of size `len(df)`containing colors

Comment: That works in a pinch, but it doesn't break out the histograms by color along the main diagonal. Here's how it looks on my machine: http://imgur.com/pJXgVpJ

Comment: Right, then your solution is better.