# Is there a parameter like cmp(colormaps) of scatter3D in function: pd.plotting.scatter_matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I have code like that, classified by their label:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = iris.feature_names)

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, c=y)
```

However, I want a qualitative colormaps in the result, like the 'Dark2' in cmap

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.scatter3D(df.values[:,0], df.values[:,1], df.values[:,2], c=y, cmap = 'Dark2')
plt.show()
```

Is there some way can achieve it, besides, I find a way [in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131707/multiple-data-in-scatter-matrix)

```
color_wheel = {1: "#0392cf", 
               2: "#7bc043", 
               3: "#ee4035"}
colors = iris_data["target"].map(lambda x: color_wheel.get(x + 1))
```

Adding a color_wheel before making scatterplot, but the problem is I don't know if the color is qualitative, when the number of label is not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All unmatched `**kwargs` for [`scatter_matrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html) are passed to [`pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) so, if specific colours don't need to be assigned to specific groups, `cmap` can be passed directly to `scatter_matrix`:

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, c=y, cmap='Dark2')
```

[image: plot]